# Angular 6: disable pipe tranformations in production

Tags: angular6, angular-pipe

I have created a custom pipe which transforms a text. For example

```
{{'labels' | customPipe}}
```

The pipe is part of a library.
However, this is purely for testing purposes and I want to disable this pipe transformation when I run in production mode. Maybe, a config value which when provided to --prod flag disables the pipe also doesn't create any overhead. Is it possible in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Using environment specific variable `environment.production` you can alter the actual functionality in the customPipe.js

Refer: https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: Thanks, I have used a boolean flag for now in environment.production file to check the mode and decide whether to apply transformations else just return. However, this might cause extra overhead of calling and returning which I did not intend to do.